# Java Date problems with TIMEZONE

Tags: java, spring, date, timezone

I am struggling on this for days.

I have a date field, that gives a date on 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

My Object have this field like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date finishdate;
```

I am on UTC, and this need to work all over the world, so on UTC-7 or UTC+7

On DataBase this value need to be store with 0 hours.

When the finishdate is filled, the format give me the timezone, so, for example:

I want **2014-10-01**, with ZERO HOURS AND MINUTES AND SECONDS, on diferent timezones I catch:

2014-10-01 07:00:00:000 
or 
2014-09-01 17:00:00:000

The problem seams to be because of the Date liybrary, and i've found a solution with JODA Library, but i was told not to used it, and I need to find another solution.

So, need to convert to UTC Date, all dates,or other thing, but the day must be the same, like 1 October.

Anyone pass through this?

Comment: I always use the joda libraries for all date related fields. The conversion between timezones is simple and I believe threadsafe. Also the joda formatters (unlike the native java DateFormatter) is threadsafe

Comment: So the boss allows you to add Spring but not Joda-Time? You need to explain to the boss how very bad the bundled date-time classes and how very much you need Joda-Time. Joda-Time is widely used, stable, and well-worn. The new java.time package bundled with Java 8 is good too, inspired by Joda-Time but re-architected. Both Joda-Time and java.time have their advantages. I use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this issue.

We made an Custom Deserializer to every object of the type Date.

On ObjectMapperFactory, where we serialize or deserialize, i mapped  to another class like this:

```
 module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializerByDefault());
```

Then, on this class we did:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatWithoutTimezome = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatWithTimezone= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})");

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonParser jparser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String content = jparser.getValueAsString();
    DateFormat format=(pattern.matcher(content).matches()) ? dateFormatWithoutTimezome : dateFormatWithTimezone;        

try {
    return format.parse(content);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new JsonParseException("Date parse failed", jparser.getCurrentLocation(),e);
}
}
```

And with this, when we receive Dates on diferent format, or with timezone to be stor we can change it to what we want.

I Hope this solution can help, I was stuck on this for 3,5 days. Dates are a pain in the a**.

Answer (score 1):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library fixes issues like this, and I believe that is also the basis of the java.time package in Java 8, but for older Java versions this kind of problem occurs constantly.

The only consistent way I have seen for dealing with this without Joda time is to treat pure dates as a String ("2014-10-01") or Integer type (20141001) instead of a Date. and only convert to dates when needed in calculations.  It is a real pain though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. The answer saga56 gives may work but you'll have some very weird dates if there's any simultaneous use of the deserialiser. You need to 'new' the SimpleDateFormats each time, or (less favourably) do something else to ensure SimpleDateFormat is strictly limited to 1 thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but outdated.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `LocalDate`

A [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format, so it can be parsed directly by `LocalDate`. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2014-10-01";
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

You assume the day starts at time `00:00:00`. But that is **not always the case**. In some time zones Daylight Saving Time (DST) or possibly other anomalies can mean the day starts at some other time on the clock such as `01:00:00`. Let java.time determine the starting time of the first moment of a day. Specify a time zone, and assuming the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) bundled with Java is up-to-date, then a call to [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) produces a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for your date and first moment.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

If you want the first moment of the day in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), specify the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) (`ZoneOffset` being a subclass of `ZoneId`).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Alternatively, use the more appropriate `OffsetDateTime` class. This is for values with a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but lacking the set of rules for handling anomalies such as DST found in a full [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). In UTC the day always starts at `00:00:00` which is stored in a constant [`LocalTime.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN).

```
OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.of( LocalTime.MIN , ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime odt = localDate.atTime( offsetTime );
```

## Database

For database work, if you want a date-only value stored you should be using a data type along the lines of the [SQL Standard type of `DATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types).

For a date-time value, nearly every serious database converts incoming data into UTC for storage in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type column. Your JDBC driver should help with this. But test and experiment as the behavior of drivers and databases varies *tremendously*.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you may be able to pass/fetch the java.time types directly via `setObject`/`getObject`. If not, convert to java.sql types via new methods added to the old classes.